# What are the options available to get Primary Key Column Names in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to fetch all Primary Keys, their parent Table Name , Column Name, and Schema Name together.
I am using INFORMATION_SCHEMA for all metadata fetching, SHOW PRIMARY KEYS/DESCRIBE TABLE does the job but it's not an option here.

Need something similar to SELECT *FROM DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.XXX.
What are the options we have here?

*I am Using JDBC

Comment: [How to get list of table primary keys in snowflake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67684963/how-to-get-list-of-table-primary-keys-in-snowflake)

Comment: With JDBC this will be difficult , we need a single query to get this.

Comment: An option is always to wrap the code with stored procedure and use `CALL get_pk_keys(schema/table)`?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using: getPrimaryKeys(String, String, String)

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-api.html#object-databasemetadata

Comment: Sounds  a good option , let me try with this , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A while back, I wrote a user defined table function (UDTF) to get the PK column(s) for a single table, each column in the PK as a single row in the return. I extended it to return a table with all the columns in PKs in an entire database.

Once you create the UDTF, you can get all the PKs for a database like this:

```
select * from table(get_pk_columns(get_ddl('database', 'MY_DB_NAME')));
```

It will return a table with columns for the schema name, table name, and column name(s). Note that if there's a composite PK, it shows in the table as one row per column. You can of course use an aggregate function such as listagg() to change that into a single row with the columns names of the composite PK separated by commas.

It's possible that if you have a very large number of tables/columns in your database, the return of the GET_DDL() function will be too large to fit into the 16mb limit. If it does fit, this should return the results quickly.

```
/********************************************************************************************************
*                                                                                                       *
* User defined table function (UDTF) to get all primary keys for a database.                            *
*                                                                                                       *
* @param  {string}:  DATABASE_DDL The DDL for the database to get the PKs. Usually use GET_DDL()       *
* @return {table}:                A table with the columns comprising the table's primary key           *
*                                                                                                       *
********************************************************************************************************/
create or replace function GET_PK_COLUMNS(DATABASE_DDL string)
returns table ("SCHEMA_NAME" string, "TABLE_NAME" string, PK_COLUMN string)
language javascript
as
$$
{
    processRow: function get_params(row, rowWriter, context){
    
        var startTableLine = -1;
        var endTableLine = -1;
    
        var dbDDL = row.DATABASE_DDL.replace(/'[\s\S]*'/gm, '')
    
        var lines = dbDDL.split("\n");
        var currentSchema = "";
        var currentTable = "";
    
        var ln = 0;
        var tableDDL = "";
        var pkCols = null;
        var c = 0;

        for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        
            if (lines[i].match(/^create .* schema /)) {
                currentSchema = lines[i].split("schema")[1].replace(/;/, '');
                //rowWriter.writeRow({PK_COLUMN: "currentSchema = " + currentSchema});
            }
        
        
            if (lines[i].match(/^create or replace TABLE /)) {
                startTableLine = i;
            }
            
            if (startTableLine != -1 && lines[i] == ");") {
                endTableLine = i;
            }
            
            if (startTableLine != -1 && endTableLine != -1) {
                // We found a table. Now, join it and send it for parsing
                tableDDL = "";
                for (ln = startTableLine; ln <= endTableLine; ln++) {
                    if (ln > 0) tableDDL += "\n";
                    tableDDL += lines[ln];
                }
                startTableLine = -1;
                endTableLine = -1;
                currentTable = getTableName(tableDDL);
                pkCols = getPKs(tableDDL);

                for (c = 0; c < pkCols.length; c++) {
                    rowWriter.writeRow({PK_COLUMN: pkCols[c], SCHEMA_NAME: currentSchema, TABLE_NAME: currentTable});
                }
            }
        }

        function getTableName(tableDDL) {
            var lines = tableDDL.split("\n");
            var s = lines[1];
            s = s.substring(s.indexOf(" TABLE ") + " TABLE ".length);
            s = s.split(" (")[0];
            return s;
        }

        function getPKs(tableDDL) {
            var c;
            var keyword = "primary key";
            var ins = -1;
            var s = tableDDL.split("\n");
            for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {  
                ins = s[i].indexOf(keyword);
                if (ins != -1) {
                    var colList = s[i].substring(ins + keyword.length);
                    colList = colList.replace("(", "");
                    colList = colList.replace(")", "");
                    var colArray = colList.split(",");
                    for (pkc = 0; c < colArray.length; pkc++) {
                        colArray[pkc] = colArray[pkc].trim();
                    }
                    return colArray;
                }
            }
            return [];  // No PK
        }
    }
}
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this using a very simple SQL based UDTF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION admin.get_primary_key(p_table_nm VARCHAR)
  RETURNS TABLE(column_name VARCHAR, ordinal_position int)
AS
  WITH t AS (select get_ddl('TABLE', p_table_nm) tbl_ddl)
     , t1 AS (
              SELECT POSITION('primary key (', tbl_ddl) + 13 pos
                   , SUBSTR(tbl_ddl, pos, POSITION(')', tbl_ddl, pos) - pos ) str
                FROM t
)
  SELECT x.value column_name
       , x.index ordinal_position
    FROM t1
       , LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(t1.str, ',') x
;
```

You can then query this in a SQL statement:

```
select *
  FROM TABLE(admin.get_primary_key('<your table name>'));
```

Unfortunately, due to the odd implementation of GET_DDL(), it will only accept a string literal and you can't use this function with a lateral join to information_schema.tables. Get the following error:

> SQL compilation error: Invalid value [CORRELATION(T.TABLE_SCHEMA) ||
> '.' || CORRELATION(T.TABLE_NAME)] for function '2', parameter
> EXPORT_DDL: constant arguments expected